# Is there a way to access uvm_phase from the testbench top?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

Is there a way to know in my testbench top about the current phase of the UVM hierarchy?. Since testbench top is a static module and UVM hierarchy is made of classes which are dynamic.

In my testbench top, I am directly driving few ports which is outside of UVM hierarchy. I need to stop driving these ports say after the shutdown phase. I can do it using uvm_config_db passing a phase from sequence but I don't want to create dependencies. I know it defeats the purpose of using UVM and reusability but just asking if I can do that?.

```
module top()

     initial begin
         drive_ports();
     end

     virtual task drive_ports()
         //I need to keep driving these ports till shutdown_phase
         if (!uvm_tb_hierarchy.phase == shutdown_phase) //?? How to get phase??
         dut.port = 8'hff
         dut.en = 1;
     endtask

     initial begin
         run_test()
     end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this to get the current phase.

```
uvm_root top;
uvm_phase curr_phase.
uvm_coreservice_t cs = uvm_coreservice_t::get();
top = cs.get_root();
curr_phase = top.m_current_phase;
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried the below code and it works. It seems each phase can be accessed at testbench top using "uvm_top.m_current_phase" provided you import uvm_pkg at testbench top. Since build_phase() starts at time 0, accessing this variable using initial_begin in testbench top was resulting in error So added wait statement

Comment: Yup. initially you may need to add wait, but then it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, I tried the below code and it works. It seems each phase can be accessed at testbench top using "uvm_top.m_current_phase" provided you import uvm_pkg at testbench top. Since build_phase() starts at time 0, accessing this variable using initial_begin in testbench top was resulting in runtime error. So added wait statement in top TB and it works.

```
module top();
import uvm_pkg::*;

int shutdown;

initial begin
    wait (uvm_top != null);
    while (1) begin
        @(uvm_top.m_current_phase);
        if (uvm_top.m_current_phase != null) begin
            case (uvm_top.m_current_phase.get_name())
                "pre_shutdown": shutdown = 1;
            endcase
        end
     end
   end
endmodule
```